# Dipole operator in a lattice model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lattice-model, dipole-moment

If I have a lattice Hamiltonian, say for example the Hubbard model
$$H = \sum_{j,k, \sigma} t_{j,k} \hat{c}^\dagger_{j \sigma}\hat{c}_{k \sigma} + U\sum_{j} \hat{n}_{j \uparrow}\hat{n}_{j \downarrow},$$
and I want to make it interact with an electromagnetic field, in the dipolar approximation I would write it
$$H_I = -\vec{\hat{D}} \cdot \vec{\hat{E}}, $$
where the electric field is given by boson operators:
$$\vec{\hat{E}}=\sum_{\vec{k},\lambda}w_k^{-1/2} \vec{e}_\lambda(\vec{k}) \left(\hat{b}_\lambda(\vec{k}) - \hat{b}^\dagger_\lambda(\vec{k})  \right)$$
(up to a prefactor).

But how can I write in the lattice model the dipolar operator $\vec{\hat{D}}$? That is, I would like to write the dipolar operator, usually written in space representation as $\sum_i q_i \hat{r}_i,$ in terms of the lattice operators $\hat{c}_{j\sigma}$ \ $\hat{c}^\dagger_{j\sigma}$

Answer (score 0):

If each lattice site is considered a state, then the usual second quantization procedure means expanding the wave function as
$$
\psi_\sigma(\mathbf{r})=\sum_{j,\sigma}\phi\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{R}_j\right)\chi_\sigma c_{j,\sigma},
$$
where $\phi\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{R}_j\right)$ is the orbital or a Wannier function centered on the $j$-th site. (Wannier functions are orthogonal, and this form a real basis, but one usually uses non-orthogonal functions, whose oevrlap is related to tight-binding approximation hopping integral.)

Given any operator in space representation, e.g.,
$$
H_I=-e\mathbf{r}\mathbf{E},$$
we can now convert it to the second quantized form.